# Generate a dummy variable satisfying a condition for the same individual in a panel dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of this form

```
ID panelid dummy1 dummy2
1  1       0      1
1  2       1      0
2  1       1      0
2  2       0      1
3  1       1      0
3  2       1      0
4  1       0      1
4  2       0      1
```

I want to generate a dummy variable equal to one in occurrence of panelid==2 and only if the same individual presents a value for the dummy1 equal to 1 in panelid==1 and a value for the dummy2 equal to 1 in panelid==2. Thus I want to obtain something like this

```
    ID panelid dummy1 dummy2 result
    1  1       0      1      0
    1  2       1      0      0
    2  1       1      0      0
    2  2       0      1      1
    3  1       1      0      0
    3  2       1      0      0
    4  1       0      1      0
    4  2       0      1      0
```

Can someone help me with these?

Many thanks to everyone

Comment: What are the conditions for `1`? (`panelid == 1` and `dummy1 == 1`) or (`panelid == 2` and `dummy2 == 1`)?

Comment: Both of them. I want to have ones for all individuals that have dummy1 == 1 in panelid==1 and dummy2==1 in panelid==2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost identical solution to @Cole's solution.

```
dataset <- read.table(text = 'ID panelid dummy1 dummy2
1  1       0      1
1  2       1      0
2  1       1      0
2  2       0      1
3  1       1      0
3  2       1      0
4  1       0      1
4  2       0      1',
                      header = TRUE)

temp_ID <- dataset$ID[(dataset$panelid == 1) & (dataset$dummy1 == 1)]
dataset$result <- as.integer(x = ((dataset$panelid == 2) & (dataset$dummy2 == 1) & (dataset$ID %in% temp_ID)))

dataset

  ID panelid dummy1 dummy2 result
1  1       1      0      1      0
2  1       2      1      0      0
3  2       1      1      0      0
4  2       2      0      1      1
5  3       1      1      0      0
6  3       2      1      0      0
7  4       1      0      1      0
8  4       2      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R approach:

```
dummy1_in_panelid <- with(df, ID[panelid == 1 & dummy1 == 1])

#initialize
df$result <- 0

df$result[with(df, which(panelid == 2 & ID %in% dummy1_in_panelid & dummy2 == 1))] <- 1
df

  ID panelid dummy1 dummy2 result
1  1       1      0      1      0
2  1       2      1      0      0
3  2       1      1      0      0
4  2       2      0      1      1
5  3       1      1      0      0
6  3       2      1      0      0
7  4       1      0      1      0
8  4       2      0      1      0
```

And the data...

```
df <- as.data.frame(data.table::fread('
ID panelid dummy1 dummy2
1  1       0      1
1  2       1      0
2  1       1      0
2  2       0      1
3  1       1      0
3  2       1      0
4  1       0      1
4  2       0      1'))
```